# Calculate values between two dicts in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dict in python one of quantities and the other of prices the both have the same keys
What is the best, and quicks way to calculate Quantity * price for each element in the dict

Example

```
prices = {'a': '40', 'b': '40', 'c': '35'}
data ={'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '4'}
```

I want to get a total sum (int) of 260

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum` over a generator expression like this:

`sum(float(v)*float(prices[k]) for k,v in data.iteritems())`

Comment: `sum(float(v)*float(prices.get(k, 0)) for k,v in data.items())` ?

Comment: I would prefer to have an exception raised in the case for we have no price for an item, rather than assume it is free.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not deleting my suggestion so that your comment remains understandable, but +1

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> prices = {'a': '40', 'b': '40', 'c': '35'}
>>> data ={'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '4'}
>>> sum(int(prices[x])*int(data[x]) for x in data)
260
```

Comment: Naturally, the data really should have been integers to avoid the need for conversion

Comment: this will break for the more general case where not every element from prices is purchased.  i.e., it makes more sense for the loop to be over data rather than over prices.

Comment: @wim what about `sum(int(a)*int(b) for a,b in zip(data.values(),prices.values()))`

Comment: Why loop over `prices` instead of `data`?  What if `data` is missing an entry that `prices` contains?

Comment: now you are assuming the dicts are sorted in corresponding order, even worse!

Comment: @wim, ah! yes you're right, it somehow gave correct solution. It was surely bad.